# How to remove/disable gdb-peda in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, gdb

While learning debugging,I somehow went into installing gdb and then gdb-peda.But now, I would like to uninstall ***gdb-peda***.Can anyone pls guide me ?

Answer (score 12):

Actually peda-gdb doesn't really install any executable in your computer.

All the peda-gdb does is to modify the config file of gdb.
This file is by default located at ~/.gdbinit.

- use `cat ~/.gdbinit` can you peek how does peda do
- Therefore, to go back to vanilla gdb, there are 2 solutions

  1. `gdb --nx`

     - This is a better way, since you may need peda someday
  2. `rm -rf ~/.gdbinit`

     - This will remove the config file of gdb, so what peda did will have no effect on your gdb now.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the Peda folder, should be somewhere in your Home directory. After that you should have your old gdb back.